# capture parameters of a URL from servlet

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, web

I have two web applications. When the user clicks on a link in the first application the second one appears. I have included a user registration id as a parameter to the URL of the link. In the second application I wrote a servlet to capture the user registration id.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            int userId= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("userId"));

        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Any body please tell me should I mention the URL of the link any where in the second application. Otherwise from where the servelet gets userId parameter. I am very new to java web stuff. Please help me.

since my question is not clear I'll put another sample below.
Below is my service.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

@GET
@Path("/{email}")
public Response getUserDetails(@PathParam("email") String email){
    String output = "User info ..  "+email ;
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

below is my servlet.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            String parameter= request.getParameter("email");

        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

My url is ...`localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/rest/hello/hasi@gmail.com`
I want to get "hasi@gmail.com" to the parameter variable in the servlet. Please help me to do this.

Comment: please include your imports.

Answer (score 0):

If your second application needs the userid parameter. You can just pass it in the link in your first application and in second application you will get it. I think you have done it properly.

"Any body please tell me should I mention the URL of the link any where in the second application. "
- Not sure about what exactly you want here, but in the first application link if you pass the parameter, second application will get it from the request, like the way you did it.

> AFTER EDIT

use `request.getRequestURL();` this will give you the requested url. Then you can just do the string operations to get the value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think my question is not clear. So I'll put another small sample below. Please help me to settle the issue